# Dedupe a list of dictionaries by values of a specified key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, and each dictionary can have any key - value pairs. Given a key, I want to remove all the dictionaries from the list except the last one that has duplicate value for that key. If any dictionary does not have specified key, it should be in the final resultset.

In summary - dedupe the items of a list of dictionaries by the value of a specified key.

**Example :**
`list_dicts = [{'a':'apple','b':'ball'}, {'a':'apple','c':'cat'}, {'c':'cheat','d':'dog'}, {'a':'amazon','c':'cheat'}]`

The function `dedupe(list_dicts, key='a')`

should return  : `[{'a':'apple','c':'cat'}, {'c':'cheat','d':'dog'}, 'a':'amazon','c':'cheat']`

I have working code but I somehow feel there would be a much shorter and smarter way to do this.

```
def dedupe_dicts_from_dict_list(dict_list, dedupe_key):
    result = list()
    temp = dict()
    for dict_ in dict_list:
        if dedupe_key in dict_:
            temp[dict_[dedupe_key]] = dict_
        else:
            result.append(dict_)
    result.extend(temp.values())
    return result
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesnt return what you said it should. The last dictionary having 'a' is amazon, cheat, but you also returned 'apple, cat'.

Comment: Since the specified key is 'a', only the unique values of 'a' are to be returned. 'a':'amazon' and 'a':'apple' are different so both are returned. The example and code reflect the same.
In this case the 'dictionary with 'a':'apple' is deduped/

Comment: Thanks Vishal, I checked it, but I dont see merit over the code I posted. Mine is more concise and works well. I was thinking if there is some more 'pythonic' way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict


def dedupe(list_of_dicts, dedupe_key):
    temp = defaultdict(list)
    final_list_of_dict = []

    for d in list_of_dicts:
        if dedupe_key in d:
            # collects the dictionaries based on dedupe_key and the value present in that key
            temp[(dedupe_key, d[dedupe_key])].append(d)
        if dedupe_key not in d:
            # retains the dictionaries in which dedupe_key not found
            final_list_of_dict.append(d)

    for _, value in temp.items():
        final_list_of_dict.append(value[-1])

    print(final_list_of_dict)


dedupe(list_dicts, dedupe_key="a")
```

**Output:**

```
[{'c': 'cheat', 'd': 'dog'}, {'a': 'apple', 'c': 'cat'}, {'a': 'amazon', 'c': 'cheat'}]
```

Comment: Uggh. Is there nothing built in to python that makes this a one or two liner!?!!